# Windows service does nothing on production PC

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net, production

I have an application that schedules jobs using Quartz.Net. It works on my development laptop perfectly both as a winforms application (with start and stop buttons) and as a Windows Services whose `OnStart()` and `OnStop()` event code matches the start and stop button code of the winforms application. They're both in the same solution using the same "model" code (in its own project).

If I run the winforms application on the production computer it works perfectly, the jobs are executed according to their schedule as expected. However if I install and run it as a Windows Service on the production PC nothing happens! The jobs do not run.

I have no idea how to debug this. Please let me know if you have any suggestions as to what might be wrong.

Also please let me know what other information I should be providing.

Oh - dev PC is running Windows 7, production PC is running Windows 8.1! Could that be the problem? I built the service by following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx which does not indicate that anything special needs to be done for deploying to Windows 8?

Could this have something to do with environment variables (which I know nothing about)?

Here is some code which may be relevant:

The service:

```
namespace DataPump
{
    public partial class DataPumpService : ServiceBase
    { 

        private TaskManager _taskManager;

        public DataPumpService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _taskManager = new TaskManager();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _taskManager.Go();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _taskManager.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

The form code (different project):

```
namespace DataPump
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TaskManager _taskManager = new TaskManager();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _taskManager.Go(); //Loops infinitely, does not block
            label1.Text = "Running...";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Stopping...";
            _taskManager.Stop();
            label1.Text = "Idle";
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            _taskManager.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Selected code from `TaskManager` code (third project which the first two each reference):

```
public class TaskManager
{
    //...
    private IScheduler _scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
    //...

    public void Go()
    {
        if (_scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs().Count() == 0)
        {
            _scheduler.Start();
            _scheduler.AddCalendar(CalendarName, MakeSAPublicHolidayCalendar(), false, true);

            foreach (DatapumpJob job in JobList)
            {
                _scheduler.ScheduleJob(MakeJob(job), MakeTriggerCron(job));
            }
        }
    }

    //...

    public void Stop()
    {
        foreach (string name in _scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs().Select(j => j.JobDetail.Key.Name))
        {
            _scheduler.Interrupt(new JobKey(name));
        }
        _scheduler.Shutdown(true);
    }
    //...
}
```

Where `JobList` is a `get` only property that generates a `List<DatapumpJob>`where `DatapumpJob` implements `IInterrutableJob` but adds common features including a job name which gets use by  the three methods beginning `Make...` which are all private methods within the `TaskManager` class.

---

This code is to answer a question from the comments regarding `ServiceBase.Run()`:

Program.cs (auto-generated):

```
namespace DataPump
{
    static class Program
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new DataPumpService() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does the code in your app use UI controls when deployed as a service? Services that use UI controls might happen to run on one machine but is not guaranteed to run.

Comment: I've recently used that tutorial, so we believe its correct. The sample writes events to the event log. If you left them in (put them back) then you should be able to document the state of the service from the log.

Comment: The Quartz Scheduler needs to be alive (in scope) for the lifetime of the service. Where are you declaring and instantiating the Scheduler in your service? It would help if you showed us some of your code.

Comment: @user469104 No the code that with UI stuff is a separate project from the actual scheduling and job classes and a third project houses the service. So the service assemblies shouldn't have anything to do with the winforms stuff (I wouldn't think)

Comment: @allonym The service runs perfectly on the dev PC though so I'm confident I'm scoping it correctly. But I'll post some code tomorrow morning.

Comment: @aldie_lab I did not implement any of the event logging code - maybe I'll add it in if you say it provides diagnostic information...

Comment: @allonym I have added some code now

Comment: @Dan thanks, but I'm afraid I won't be of any help: your code appears sound to me, and it is reasonably similar to code that I have in a service that is working well. The Quartz scheduler is wrapped in an extra API layer in mine, but other than that it's pretty much the same mechanics. Sorry, I don't see why it isn't working for you:(

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can debug it or get some sort of diagnostic information by any chance?

Comment: I just have to ask: Are you at any point in your code calling `ServiceBase.Run()` with an instance of your service in it? I don't see it anywhere in your posted code, so I can't be sure until I ask.

Comment: @Alex I did a find over the entire solution and there is one instance of `ServiceBase.Run()` in Program.cs created by Visual Studio. I've added that code to the question for you to see.

Comment: It was a bit of a long shot, I admit. Just had to make sure, because a lack of that command would certainly cause your service not to run. :)

Comment: @Alex thanks anyways, but like I've said the service runs on the dev pc just fine. Any other suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: When you run it interactively, are you using the same account that the service is running under? In other words, does the service account have the necessary accesses to do its job?

Comment: I'm not sure, the service is set to "Log On As" `Local System`. Should I change this to something that has more permissions? Does `Network Service`?

Comment: I think this might be a network permission issue - I'm going to try this next http://serverfault.com/questions/177139/windows-service-cant-access-network-share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a network permissions issue. The service was running, it was just unable to access the network drive. So really my question was mi-specified.

After trying this: https://serverfault.com/questions/177139/windows-service-cant-access-network-share we eventually got it to work by setting the service to run as a specific user account on the PC.